# Embeber codigo Typescript en HTML

Tags: html5, angular, typescript, aplicación-web, angular7

hola estoy desarrollando una aplicacion en angular y en uno de mis componentes necesito agregar funciones en typescript dentro del html, que sean funcionales sobre el mismo componente que estoy creando en dicho html.

Se que existen js que se puenden exportar en el index del projecto para utilizar etiquetas como:

```
<script type = "text / typescript">

</script>
```

sin embargo las funciones dentro de estas estiquetas deben estar en el head del index para funcionar, pero yo necesito agrgarlas en el html del componente que tecnicamente se encuentra en el body.

¿ existe alguna otra forma de embeber codigo ts dentro del html del componente?

Comment: Según tu  pregunta, deduzco que no has entendido por completo Angular, y tienes una gran confusión al respecto. Saludos

Comment: Lo que solicitas no tiene sentido, lee lo siguiente para que sepas como trabaja typescript https://desarrolloweb.com/articulos/introduccion-a-typescript.html

Comment: vale yo entiendo la idea de angular pero el punto con el proyecto es a partir de un texto que se escribe en html y se almacena en base de datos posteriormente llamarlo y renderizarlo..... por lo cual si el componente tiene alguna función no se como podría almacenarla para luego utilizarla

Comment: Los métodos públicos de un componente en Angular pueden ser invocados directamente desde el código javascript en el HTML del template. Para entender mejor la pregunta explica en detalle si eso no te sirve por qué.

Comment: agregando esto en tu componente (`declare var $: any;`)  puedes hacer cosas como estas (`$('#juridicoTab').removeClass('activar');`) en el componente de angular .... pero no comprendo para que necesitas esto ya que en en angular se pueden hacer casi lo mismo ---- Ademas Angular es un framework construido completamente en TypeScript y, como resultado, el uso de TypeScript con Angular proporciona una experiencia perfecta.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que la mejor solución para tu caso sería crear directivas para agregar comportamiento a los templates. 
Sin embargo si queres seguir por el camino de tener una función por ejemplo **calcularNumero** en otro `typescript` y llamarla desde el *html*, lo que deberías hacer es en tu `typescript` importar ese archivo y crear una variable con esa función ejemplo:

Archivo **funcionesGenericas.ts**

```
export function calcularNumero(numero1, numero2) {
    return numero1 + numero2;
}
```

Archivo donde queres implementar:

```
import { calcularNumero } from "./funcionesGenericas";

@Component({
  selector: 'some-component',
  templateUrl: '{{calcularNumeroFunction(1, 2)}}',
  styleUrls: ['./some.component.scss']
})
export class SomeComponent {
   calcularNumeroFunction = calcularNumero;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

"Esta es una versión que escribí que usa directamente la versión de Microsoft / TypeScript / master para que siempre esté actualizada: https://github.com/basarat/typescript-script"

Esta pregunta fue respondida anteriormente. Te dejo el enlace para que veas si te sirve algo mas de allí, pero preguntaron lo mismo. Saludos https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14015899/embed-typescript-code-in-an-html-document

Créditos a: basarat user